# Azure Linux VM root volume exend

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, azure

I have created a SLES 11.4 linux machine on Azure. it comes with 30GB root volume as standard. I have attached another 1TB disk to this system, however for the software I want to install I need root volument to be extended to 500GB. i can't find a wayto resize Linux root volume through Azure GUI console. can you please help?
Regards,
Nav

Answer (score 3):

You can't resize the root volume through the portal, you will need to use PowerShell or the CLI and then SSH into the box to finish the process.
The PowerShell to resize the boot volume is:

```
$rg = “YourResourceGroupName”

$vmName = “YourVMName”
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $vmName

$vm.StorageProfile[0].OSDisk[0].DiskSizeGB = 127  # change the size as required

Update-AzureRmVM –ResourceGroupName $rg -VM $vm
```

Once that is done you then need to use FDisk to resize the partition on the machine. The steps to doing this are well documented [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/05/24/step-by-step-how-to-resize-a-linux-vm-os-disk-in-azure-arm/)